# Install sbt from source

Tags: scala, jvm, sbt

Because in my operating system distribution has not default package sbt, I try compile from source and install sbt package locally (https://github.com/sbt/sbt). Unfortunately I can not do it and I can not find any guide to do this without installed sbt. To compile sbt from source is needed sbt? What can I to do to install sbt from source?

Comment: What operating system are you using? As long as you have a _Java 8_ runtime installed, you should be able to install _SBT_ by [downloading it](https://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html). That's the beauty of _Java!_ The critical element is likely to be whether your OS supports the shell script needed to run _SBT_...

Comment: There is no need to compile. Download the generic dist and use it with your JVM.

Comment: have you seen https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Setup.html ?

Comment: At [https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Setup.html] there is an instruction how to install sbt from packages, I want to compile sbt from sources. My OS is Debian 9.4 "Stretch"

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes: to build sbt from source, you need to install sbt first (obviously, not from source). There are instructions for [Building sbt from source](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/1.x/CONTRIBUTING.md#build-from-source) and they start with

> Install the current stable binary release of sbt (see [Setup](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Setup)), which will be used to build sbt from source.

If you have a concrete problem installing sbt from binaries, you should solve it first. You can ask for help with it in a new question.